# Retrieve and print data to textboxes from mysql DB using ajax

Tags: php, ajax

I have the following text fields:

```
<input type="text" name="empid" id="empid" tabindex="1" onblur="getname()">
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" tabindex="2"/>
<input type="text" name="city" id="name" tabindex="3"/>
<input type="text" name="state" id="name" tabindex="4"/>
```

and database table is:

```
empid       name     city        state
EMP471      BBB      bbbbb       cccccc
EMP444      AAA      xxxx        yyyyyy
```

I'm new to php. I found some code on internet to retrieve data. but its not working.

Ajax code is:

```
function getname() {
    var id=$("#id").val();   
    $.ajax({
        type:"post",
        dataType:"text",
        data:"id="+id,
        url:"getinsdata.php",   
        success:function(response)
        { 
            $("#name").val(response.name);   
            $("#city").val(response.city); 
            $("#state").val(response.state); 
        }
    });
}
```

and php code is

```
<?php
    include 'connection.php';
    $id=$_POST['id'];
    $id=$_POST['id'];
    $query=mysql_query("select name,city,state from ins_master where id=$id");
    $result=mysql_fetch_row($query);
    echo $result[0];   
    exit;
?>
```

when we select the empid then the respective name, city, state should be shown in textboxes when onblur event fires in PHP using AJAX.

Comment: what have you tried so far ?

Comment: Stack Overflow is *not* a code writing service. 
We are always glad to help and support new coders but you need to help yourself first. 
You are expected to try to write the code yourself.
Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [fetching data from database and display it using ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41565907/fetching-data-from-database-and-display-it-using-ajax)

Comment: Where is `getinsdata.php`? Is it direct in the root of your website (which is probably `localhost`)? I would expect to see a path there

Comment: getinsdata.php is in the root folder only(both files are in same path).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are you trying to achieve? Send the datas and get the response according to a query? Get some datas?

I'd go

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="test" method="POST">
<input type="text" id="name" required minlength="5" name="name"/>
<input type="password"  id="pw" required name="pw"/>
<input id ="sub" type="submit"/>
</form>
<div id="answer"></div>
</body>
<script>
    $("#sub").click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        query = $.post({
            url : 'check_ajax.php',
            data : {'name': $('input[name=name]').val(), 'pw': $('#pw').val()},
        });
        query.done(function(response){
            $('#answer').html(response);
        });
    });
</script>
```

This is check_ajax.php  :

```
<?php
var_dump($_POST);

?>
```

in the second file but that's where you're supposed to do your query and insert/select

As people said we don't write code but give clues and since it's basics/fundamentals I can't help more cause you have to understand. Copy paste ain't a great idea

Comment: Btw, you have a duplicate of $id and you dont bind parameters to your query. See PDO manual

Comment: `var_dump($_POST);`?? ***Don't!!*** - I ***strongly*** urge you to get an IDE with a debugger (Eclipse, Netbeans, etc) and learn to use the debugger. That will allow you to set a “breakpoint” in a line of code, then when you run your program, the debugger will stop when it  hits that line, an you can examine the values of your variables and figure out the problem for self

Comment: There's no bug, i'm a lazy ass who didn't want to take some time writing a foreach/echo

Comment: The idea is get out of the mindset of `debug by print`, even for quickies, and not to actively promote it here. I am sure that you agree, really :-)

Comment: No probs. I do like to recommend that new guys learn the debugger; many haven't even heard of it. I will turn my eye to this one quick & dirty :-)  I guess that's OK, so long as the code isn't littered with `echo(reached line xxx);`

Comment: I don't do that. I'm really new to programming  but I don't have those really bad habits and try to make simple/understandable code . Try to start with good manners/habbits. I did use a lot of var_dump or echo/console.log a variable but mostly to check received posts

Comment: Dump to console can be OK - if you do it in a function and can easily disable that function with a single line of code when you go into production (you don't want users reading your debug output ;-)  If wrapped in a function, I recommend looking at [PHP Console](https://github.com/barbushin/php-console) and the very impressive [Kint](https://kint-php.github.io/kint/)

Comment: I only show them until I'm done with a single functionalty. I work as units. once it's good I dd (vim key on VSC) the same 1 line (dump post), sometimes I dump session too

Comment: As you say that you are "really new to programming" are you aware of our [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) site?  When your code is working and debugged, you can code there and get feedback from others about your coding style, problems you may have missed, efficiency, etc

Comment: I def need to have a look and post some code there. I have quite a harsh teacher who virtualy killed 80% of students in my class on first semester cause of bad logic and the others where asked to see how I code xD

Comment: Even if I'm new I don't seem to lack of logic, teacher actualy ask people to come by me so they have a hint on how to code. I could show some projects I did in php/js. So far I've made a Chessboard game in Node.JS, a veterinary office consultations/appointments website (php/sql/ajax), and a music_player w/ playlists/pro and non pro artists on the model of Deezer

Comment: Chess game wasn't fully complete tho, we didn't have time to finish it, but for noobs it was a beautiful site

Answer (score 1):

Try this html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function getname(val) {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'getinsdata.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: 'state_id='+val,
                dataType: 'json',
                success:function(data){
                    var len = data.length;
                    if(len > 0){
                        var id = data[0]['id'];
                        var name = data[0]['name'];
                        var city = data[0]['city'];
                        var state = data[0]['state'];

                        document.getElementById('name').value = name;
                        document.getElementById('city').value = city;
                        document.getElementById('state').value = state;    
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>

    <form method="post">
        <input type="text" name="empid" id="empid" tabindex="1"  onblur="getname(this.value);">
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" tabindex="2"/>
        <input type="text" name="city" id="city" tabindex="3"/>
        <input type="text" name="state" id="state" tabindex="4"/> 

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

and getinsdata.php is

```
<?php
    include('connection.php');
    $id = $_POST['state_id'];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM ins_master WHERE id='$id'";

    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql); 

    $users_arr = array();

    while( $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result) ){
        $id = $row['id'];
        $name = $row['name'];
        $city = $row['city'];
        $state = $row['state'];
        $users_arr[] = array("id" => $id, "name" => $name, "city" => $city, "state" => $state);
    }

    // encoding array to json format
    echo json_encode($users_arr);
    exit;
?>
```

And your connection.php

```
<?php
$username = "";
$password = "";
$dbname = "";
    $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost",$username,$password,$dbname);
    if(!$conn){
        die("Error in Connecation");    
    }
?>
```

put $dbname= your database name

Comment: Its Working... Thank you so much..  :-)